# E: Unable to locate package i7z-gui Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, apt, package-management

I'm unsure as to what I'm doing wrong but I can't seem to install i7z-gui in Linux Mint 19.3. My repositories include two groups
**PPAs/Etc:**

```
deb https://xpra.org/ bionic main
deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bit-team/stable/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/apps/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rael-gc/scudcloud/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/seafile/seafile-client/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu bionic main
```

**OS:**

```
deb http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/linuxmint-packages tricia main upstream import backport 
deb http://mirror.it.ubc.ca/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirror.it.ubc.ca/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirror.it.ubc.ca/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ bionic partner
```

As you can see, I have a few... But the main thing is that it should be in Ubuntu Universe which I clearly have "`deb http://mirror.it.ubc.ca/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse`", so I don't know what else to try given that APT is unable to locate the package when requesting and installation or search. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i7z-gui` was [dropped in version 0.27.2+git2013.10.12-g5023138-4](https://tracker.debian.org/news/901595/accepted-i7z-0272git20131012-g5023138-4-source-into-unstable/) because of the Qt4 removal. Looking at [the Ubuntu tracker](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/i7z) shows that Xenial still has `i7z-gui`, but Bionic and subsequent releases don’t.

It’s thus normal not to find the package on your setup.

Comment: Dang I should have read the version name more carefully. Thanks Stephen